# Next.js Image configuration for unsplash images not working

Tags: next.js

In part of my code, I have an next.js Image tag that resembles the following:

```
<Image 
  src = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533929736458-ca588d08c8be?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" 
  width="100" 
  height="100" 
  alt = ""
/>
```

Every time I run it, it leads to the error which says:

> Error: Invalid src prop (https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533929736458-ca588d08c8be?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80) on `next/image`, hostname "images.unsplash.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
> See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

I changed the next.config.js file numerous times but haven't succeeded yet. I've tried:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify:true,
  images:{
    remotePatterns:[
      {
        hostname:'images.unsplash.com'
      }
    ]
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

, another time with

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify:true,
  images:{
    remotePatterns:[
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.unsplash.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      }
    ]
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

but none of them have worked. They all lead to the same error message as before. Is there a configuration that would work for the following image? For further reference, I was watching the following (slightly outdated) video on next.js: https://youtu.be/KjY94sAKLlw?t=3836

Answer (score 0):

You can try this from the official Nextjs Docs:

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    domains: ['images.unsplash.com'],
  }
}
```

> Note: Nextjs recommend using remotePatterns instead so you can restrict protocol and pathname.

Comment: I've tried this too but I get the same error - perhaps there is a disconnect between next.config.js and the webpage? I'm still a beginner at next.js so I'm not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your server. It should work

Comment: I've tried that multiple times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**This one works**

```
const nextConfig = {}

const path = require('path')

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          hostname: 'images.unsplash.com', 
          //in my case i used cdn.pixabay.com
        },
      ],
    },
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host